# Adding a button in the button right side of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following android layout that displays toe list views in the screen one in left side one the other to right side.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
<ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" android:id="@+id/ListView01"/>
<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="3" android:id="@+id/ListView02"/>
```

Now I want to add a button displayed it the bottom right side of the screen.
Can anyone help me about how I could do that?

Comment: do you mean at the bottom right side or just right of the lists?

Comment: yes it was by mistake I mean bottom right side of the screen

Answer (score 2):

first remove the linear layout,use relative layout.for button use the following command

**android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"** and **android:layout_alignParentRight="true**"

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution should be: Add a RelativeLayout as root layout and put the button after the LinearLayout with properties layout_below and layout_right (LinearLayout as reference).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >
    <Button 
    android:id="@+id/click"
   android:layout_width="100dip"
  android:layout_height="60dip"
  android:text="Click"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  />

  <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:id="@+id/ListView02"
        android:background="#00ff00" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/click"
        />
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ListView01"
        android:background="#000000" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/ListView02"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: actually I want my button to be down from listaview2